# Regexp doesn't evaluate meta-character \w

Tags: regex, racket

Fiddling around in Racket I'm trying to write a simple lexer that uses regular expressions to handle patterns, but it doesn't seem to want to work with the meta-character `\w`.

```
#lang racket

(define (tokenize-broken str)
  (match str
    ["\"" 'StringDelim]
    [(regexp #rx"#\\w+") 'Message]
    [_ 'Undefined]))

(define (tokenize-working str)
  (match str
    ["\"" 'StringDelim]
    [(regexp #rx"#[a-zA-Z_]+") 'Message]
    [_ 'Undefined]))
```

Now when I try to run them in the repl I get this:

```
> (tokenize-broken "#msg")
'Undefined
> (tokenize-working "#msg")
'Message
```

So what's going on here? why can't I get `\w` to work? It works fine in other languages supporting regular expressions, so why not here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `\w` is not included in `regexp`. Try `pregexp` (ie, "Perl" regexp), and use `#px` instead of `#rx`.

```
(define (tokenize-fixed str)
  (match str
    ["\"" 'StringDelim]
    [(pregexp #px"#\\w+") 'Message]
    [_ 'Undefined]))

> (tokenize-fixed "#msg")
'Message
```

It works: http://pasterack.org/pastes/19596

Comment: In match, having both `regexp` and `#rx` is necessary, because an `#rx` without `regexp` matches a regexp equal to that, right? [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match%29%29)

Comment: It works because you didn't use `#rx`, but use `#px` instead